# FMX e Styles - Colocar um Style unico para todo o projeto

Tags: delphi, style

Boa tarde..
Em um projeto VCL nos selecionamos um Style e ele fica em todo o projeto.
Gostaria de sabe se é possível usar um style
em todo o projeto FMX.
Sei que se colocar um styleBook em cada form funciona, mas será que tem uma opção de colocar um style único para todo o projeto?

Answer (score 0):

Penso que a unica alternativa é pôr o StyleBook num DataModule e partilhar com todos os forms.

Comment: Bom dia Tiago.. essa é uma das possibilidades sim.. obrigado pela atenção :)